# Disable get latest on checkout TFS

Tags: tfs

I have to revert a project to last weeks edition.  So  I got a specific version by date, but now if I add a space to a file it checks out and gets latest.

I went to Tools -> options -> source control -> VS TFS -> "Get latest version on checkout" -> unchecked.

Then I went to Tools -> Source Control Settings -> "Enable get latest on check-out" -> unchecked.

But the behavior still happens!  Not sure what to try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to restart Visual Studio to see the change.  :|